# SWIG JAVA typemaps configuration

Tags: java, c++, swig, typemaps

Here is SWIG typemap, that converts C++  types to Python types.

```
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
  %typemap(in) (char *data, size_t datasize) {
    Py_ssize_t len;
    PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input, &$1, &len);
    $2 = (size_t)len;
  }

  %typemap(in, numinputs=0) (char **data, size_t *datasize)(char *temp, size_t tempsize) {
    $1 = &temp;
    $2 = &tempsize;
  }

  %typemap(argout) (char **data, size_t *datasize) {
    if(*$1) {
      $result = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(*$1, *$2);
      free(*$1);
    }
  }
#endif
```

Can you please do the same, but for java language? so the answer will be like

```
#ifdef SWIGJAVA
  %typemap(in) (char *data, size_t datasize) {
    convertJavaBytesToC++Bytes();
    ...something else...
  }
...
```

So I need it to generate proper JAVA wrapper code

Function declarations in C++ which I want to translate to JAVA:

```
public void getFrames(char **data, size_t *datasize) {
    std::string s = getFramesAsString();
    size_t size = s.length();
    char *c = new char[size];
    s.copy(c, size, 0);
    *datasize = size;
    *data = c;
};
public void putFrame(char *data, size_t datasize) {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(frames_mtx);
    frames.push_front(std::string(data, datasize));
};
```

Comment: What have you done to solve your own problem? If you won't make an effort to solve your own problem, what makes you think strangers will do it for you? It sounds like you should have a chat with your supervisor instead.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I am reading C++ and SWIG manuals right now) Sooner or later I will solve this problem, but it will take a very long time

Comment: The information that's missing here to really be able to help is what are the semantics of the C function you want to wrap? at a guess I'd say it's a function that returns bytes of a given size through it's arguments as outputs only. But it's hard to be sure what the function you're trying to wrap actually looks like without seeing a declaration and stub/dummy definition of it.

Comment: @Flexo I added declarations of functions. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG already has a typemap for Java which does this for you. To use it all you need to do is use `%apply` to tell SWIG it is what you want to use for those parameters:

e.g.

```c
%module test

%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (char *data, size_t datasize) }

void putFrame(char *data, size_t datasize);
```

which will generate the following Java function:

```
  public static void putFrame(byte[] data) {
    ...
```

Which exactly matches the semantics you want.

Comment: Thank you. What about "void getFrames(char **data, size_t *datasize)"?

Comment: What are the semantics for that function? They're likely to be different, but hard to guess from the signature alone. (Probably it's an output for an array of a given size, but no way to be sure at all, particularly around ownership of memory to avoid leaks)

Comment: This function should return an array of bytes. However, in c++ the function cannot return an array, so this function should take byte array by reference, and put bytes into that array.

Comment: It is not the signature alone. I also put function body in the question: public void getFrames(char **data, size_t *datasize) {
    std::string s = getFramesAsString();
    size_t size = s.length();
    char *c = new char[size];
    s.copy(c, size, 0);
    *datasize = size;
    *data = c;
};